# Initalizer file not working correctly with Rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter

I am trying to use the sentimental gem to perform basic sentiment analysis on tweets. I have instantiated Sentimental in an initializer file, and tried to call the function on a tweet's text, but instead got the error:

```
undefined method `sentiment' for nil:NilClass
```

referring to this line:

```
 <%= $analyzer.sentiment(t.text) %>
```

**initializers/sentimental.rb**

```
$analyzer = Sentimental.new
$analyzer.load_defaults
```

**home.html.erb**

```
<ul>
    <% query = params["q"] %>
      <% if query != nil and query.chars.include? "#" %>
        <% TwitterApi.search_twitter(query).each do |t| %>
          <% tweet = TwitterApi.embed(t)%>
          <%= raw(tweet.html) %>
          <%= $analyzer.sentiment(t.text)%>
          <li><%= t.text %></li>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume this example should do the trick:

```
# controller

before_action :set_analyzer, only: [:needed_action]

# ... some code

def set_analyzer
  @analyzer ||= Sentimental.new
  @analyzer.load_defaults
end

# home.html.erb

<ul>
    <% query = params["q"] %>
      <% if query != nil and query.chars.include? "#" %>
        <% TwitterApi.search_twitter(query).each do |t| %>
          <% tweet = TwitterApi.embed(t)%>
          <%= raw(tweet.html) %>
          <%= @analyzer.sentiment(t.text)%>
          <li><%= t.text %></li>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's strange that your global variable is not being set. Are you sure that you restarted your server after this?

If that still doesn't work, here's an approach I think might work:

```
#use a constant in your initializer
SentimentAnalyzer = Sentimental.new
SentimentAnalyzer.load_defaults
```